# Why will my google doubleclick code work when converted to coffeescript if I use the "window" object but not if I use "@" object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

My understanding is that inside of a coffeescript function, "this" or "@" is equal to "window"  (at least in the context of Rails).  Why is it then that I can get this code to work:

```
window.googletag = window.googletag or {}
window.googletag.cmd = window.googletag.cmd or []

window.googletag.cmd.push ->
  window.googletag.defineSlot('/1003175/ad-name-here', [336, 280], 'div-gpt-ad-1349373630997-0').addService(window.googletag.pubads())
  window.googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest()
  window.googletag.enableServices()
```

but not this code

```
@googletag = @googletag or {}
@googletag.cmd = @googletag.cmd or []

@googletag.cmd.push ->
  @googletag.defineSlot('/1003175/ad-name-here', [336, 280], 'div-gpt-ad-1349373630997-0').addService(@googletag.pubads())
  @googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest()
  @googletag.enableServices()
```

When I place in my code alert(@ == window) I get true.. if they are the same then why would one work but not the other?  Is there not a more graceful way to write this code then appending window to every instance of the word googletag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In coffeescript, the `@` is equivalent to `this`, but the value of `this` is dependent on your current scope within the code. In your example, `alert(@ == window)` returns true because *in that context* `this` is the window. But when you use it in another context, for example inside a function definition (`@googletag.cmd.push -> ...`) then it will get the context of whatever scope that function is called from.

In the end this is not a coffeescript issue but a Javascript issue. I'd recommend reading up a bit more on `this`, it's a somewhat confusing concept at first.

Here's one article that helped me understand the concept better: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: Thanks!  That gave me the clue I needed to use a double arrow instead of a single to bind the scope of this.  Works now.. thanks!

Comment: Yes the double arrow is a nice trick! Added a reference on `this` if you're interested.